# Conormal sheaf in the analytic category and Kähler differentials

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

As discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6074/kahler-differentials-and-ordinary-differentials) the Kähler differentials $\Omega^1_K$ and the ordinary differentials $\Omega^1$ of a complex manifold $(M,\mathcal{O}_M)$ are not the same. As sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_M$-modules, $\Omega^1$ is finitely generated while $\Omega^1_K$ is not.

Now, Kähler differentials may be constructed as follows:

Take $\mathcal{O}_M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_M\to \mathcal{O}_M$ the multiplication map and denote by $J$ its kernel. Then $\Omega^1_K\cong J/J^2$.

On the other hand, take the multiplication $\mathcal{O}_M\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_M\to \mathcal{O}_M$ of the analytic tensor product ($\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^k}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^l}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{k+l}}$) and denote its kernel by $I$. Then $I/I^2\cong \Omega^1$.

It confuses me that these two construction give two wildly different answer.

For example I tried to prove $de^x=e^xdx$ in $I/I^2$ and have not been able to do so. One has to prove that in $\mathcal{O}_M\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_M$ the following holds

$1\hat{\otimes}e^x - e^x\hat{\otimes} 1 \mod I^2 = e^x(1 \hat{\otimes}x - x \hat{\otimes}1) \mod I^2$.

Moreover, however this proof works, it needs to fail if one tries to adapt the proof for the ideal $J$. Has someone worked this out explicitly or any ideas on how to do this? It should probably be a rather neat calculation.

In general, the tensor product $\mathcal{O}_M\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathcal{O}_M$ is quite weird in the analytic category as it does not describe an analytic space. All of this probably just exemplifies that the fiber product in the algebraic category is different to the analytic fiber product.

Comment: First, you have to be more precise about the "completed tensor product" of topological vector spaces. Maybe you would take the projective tensor product of topological vector spaces. Second, the analytic cotangent sheaf is not given by $J/J^2$ as you wrote — you have to take some kind of completion or closure of $J^2$. In this case, you could rewrite $1\otimes f-f\otimes1$ using the Taylor formula (note that this is a glorious $f(y)-f(x)$), and since you completed $J^2$, you could take the sum of a convergent series instead of a finite sum of elements in $J^2$

Comment: The analytic tensor product can be defined without the use of a topology. One sets $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^k}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^l}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{k+l}}$ and defines the tensor product of quotients by quotienting out $J_1\hat{\otimes} 1 + 1 \hat{\otimes} J_2$. One can show that this satisfies the universal properties of a tensor product. A reference is "Analytische Stellenalgebren - Grauert & Remmert". I do not understand your remark about the ideal. I think you got $I$ and $J$ confused.

Comment: I meant by $I$, yes. Anyway, the idea is that, for example, if you consider the special case of affine lines, then the kernel is generated by $1\otimes t-t\otimes1$. Let $x:=1\otimes t,y:=t\otimes1$, then by Taylor's formula $f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)f'(y)+(x-y)^2(\cdots)$ holds in a neighborhood of the diagonal, where the second summand lies in $I^2$. (Since the objects are of finite type, $I^2$ is automatically complete, so my comment is not necessary.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the calculation is actually quite simple. As @Yai0Phah correctly mentioned the analytic tensor product differs from the tensor product over $\mathbb{C}$ in the fact that infinite sums for convergent power series commute with the tensor product.

Now, note that

$(1\otimes x - x \otimes 1)(1\otimes x^n - x^n\otimes 1)= 1\otimes x^{n+1} - x\otimes x^n - x^n\otimes x + x^{n+1}\otimes 1$

vanishes in $I/I^2$. Expanding $e^x$ as a power series and then commuting the tensor product shows that all one has to show is:

$(\frac{1}{(i-1)!}x^{i-1} \otimes 1)(1\otimes x - x \otimes 1) \mod I^2 = (1\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^i - \frac{1}{i!}x^i \otimes 1) \mod I^2$

But this follows from the vanishing of the above product in the following way:

\begin{align*}(1\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^i - \frac{1}{i!}x^i \otimes 1) &= x\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-1} + \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-1}\otimes x - 2\frac{1}{i!} x^i\otimes 1\\
&=(x\otimes 1 )( 1\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-1} + \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-2}\otimes x - 2\frac{1}{i!} x^{i-1}\otimes 1)\\
&=(x\otimes 1 )( x\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-2} + 2\frac{1}{i!}x^{i-2}\otimes x - 3\frac{1}{i!} x^{i-1}\otimes 1)\\
&=(x^2\otimes 1 )( 1\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x^{i-2} + 2\frac{1}{i!}x^{i-3}\otimes x - 3\frac{1}{i!} x^{i-2}\otimes 1)
\end{align*}

Doing this $(i-1)$-times leads to

\begin{align*}(x^{i-2}\otimes 1)(x\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x + (i-1)x\otimes \frac{1}{i!}x - i \frac{1}{i!}x \otimes 1)&=(x^{i-1}\otimes 1) \frac{1}{(i-1)!}(1\otimes x - x \otimes 1).
\end{align*}

Which is what needs to be shown. All the above equations are to be considered $\mod I^2$.